# Only POST requests with iisnode unauthorized

Tags: node.js, post, iis, iisnode

I have an Express API running on IIS with iisnode. I have only Windows Authentication enabled and can send GET requests.

POST requests however return "401 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

I include credentials in the React fetch request:

```
await fetch("https://website", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: etc..)
```

and in my Express code:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "https://website", credentials: true }))
```

I have the CORS module installed and in my web.config I have:

```
<cors enabled="true">
    <add origin="https://website" allowCredentials="true">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    </add>
</cors>
```

I also have in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <add accessType="Allow" verbs="GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT" users="*"/>
        <allow roles="*" users="*" />
        <deny users=?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I have tried removing "WebDAV" but that did not work. I also have set "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" to allow all verbs. My web.config contains all the necessary code to make iisnode work, which I have not included in the post. I also tried adding a "allowMethods" tag inside the CORS tag but that did not work.

Any ideas on why my GET and OPTIONS requests validate correctly, but my POST requests get blocked? A solution should not include enabling "Anonymous authentication" because that is not an option.

Comment: First of all, check in the developer tools of your browser if the credentials are actually sent or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing the `<add accessType="Allow" verbs="GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT" users="*" />` line from within authorization.

Comment: It is good to hear that your issue is resolved now. I would suggest you mark your own answer to this question. It could help other community members in the future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.